# Duplicate style tags in NextJS with component library

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js, rollup

I currently have a component library that's set up like a monorepo using Lerna + nx. During the build pipeline, the packages are built and published on an internal registry. Each package is built using rollup, and the styles are injected into the consumer application (not sure if it's important, but we're using CSS modules + SCSS).

The problem is that some components are dependencies for other components (for example a `<Button />` component could be a dependency of a `<Modal />` component). The problem is that in the consumer application (NextJS), we are getting duplicate `<style>` tags for the number of times `<Button />` appears as a dependency (ex: we would get one for `<Button />` and one for `<Modal />`).

Here's the rollup config each package uses (the inject property is something we set up to get SSR working with styles in the consumer app):

```
const { babel } = require("@rollup/plugin-babel")
const resolve = require("@rollup/plugin-node-resolve")
const commonjs = require("@rollup/plugin-commonjs")
const postcss = require("rollup-plugin-postcss")
const { externals } = require("rollup-plugin-node-externals")
const typescript = require("@rollup/plugin-typescript")

const path = require("path")

const plugins = {
  typescript: typescript({ compilerOptions: { declarationDir: "/" }, filterRoot: path.resolve("..", "..") }),
  externals: externals(),
  postcss: postcss({
    modules: {
      generateScopedName: "[name]_[local]_[hash:base64:6]",
    },
    use: ["sass"],
    inject: (varname) => {
      return `
      import originalInjector from "style-inject/dist/style-inject"
      const injectCss = (css) => {
        if (typeof document === "undefined") {
          if (global.ssrStyles) {
            global.ssrStyles = global.ssrStyles + " " + css
          } else {
            global.ssrStyles = css
          }
        }
        originalInjector(css, {
          insertAt: "top",
          singleTag: true,
        })
      }
      injectCss(${varname});`
    },
  }),
  resolve: resolve(),
  babel: babel({ babelHelpers: "bundled", rootMode: "upward" }),
  commonjs: commonjs(),
}

module.exports = [
  {
    input: "./src/index.ts",
    output: [
      {
        sourcemap: true,
        file: "./lib/index.js",
        format: "es",
        globals: { react: "React" },
      },
      {
        sourcemap: true,
        file: "./lib/index.cjs.js",
        format: "cjs",
        globals: { react: "React" },
      },
    ],
    plugins: [plugins.typescript, plugins.externals, plugins.postcss, plugins.resolve, plugins.babel, plugins.commonjs],
  }
]
```

For the sake of brevity, here's a rudimentary example of the issue:

```
/* Component A */
import styles from "./styles.module.scss";

const ComponentA = () => {
  <div className={styles.wrapper} />
}

/* Component B */
import ComponentA from "@my-registry/ComponentA";

const ComponentB = () => {
  <ComponentA />
}

/* consumer app */
import ComponentA from "@my-registry/ComponentA";
import ComponentB from "@my-registry/ComponentB";

const App = () => {
  <ComponentA />
  <ComponentB />
}
```

Currently the consumer application would receive 3 style tags: 1 for `ComponentB` and 2 for `ComponentA` (from the import in the consumer application, and from it also being a dependency for `ComponentB`). Is this an issue with how we're building these packages, or is there something we can set up in the consumer application for deduping these style tags?